# Should we await a sigificant difference of performance between a standalone Neo4j website backend versus a Neo4J + MySQL solution?

Tags: mysql, database-design, neo4j, nosql, graph-databases

We are working with a friend on a website concept based on erotic essays with collaborative writting. She has a very good pen and we both have knowledge of web development.

The key is to keep the readers on the site after that they read the first essay. For this purpose we have designed a recommendation system based on a graph database. We are thinking of implementing it with Neo4j.

Now the question is: should we put everything in Neo4j or separate it with articles in MySQL and metadata in Neo4j?

Some of the key questions are :

- Performance under load peaks
- Simplicity of implementation
- Cache management with Django
- Avoiding to seach twice in two different databases
- Keeping a light graph to improve graph queries
- Keeping a simple version management
- Other alternatives like RedisGraph + ReJSON

Well, it is mostly ease of implementation versus performance. But I don't know if there is a significant difference of performances between these solutions.

It's still a bit little complicated in my head so your feedback is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: No. Lol... It is either Neo4j + MySQL OR RedisGraph + ReJSON OR Neo4j OR RedisGraph. ^-^'

Comment: Do you have a feel for what the bottleneck will be?  Disk size / accessing data from disk / RAM size (maybe everything can be cached there) / simplicity of "graphing" (coding simplicity, that is) / flexibility (often conflicts with simplicity).  You mentioned "version mgt" -- is that data versioning?  schema versioning?  code versioning?  "Graph db" -- Hierarchical?  DAG?  Generating line graphs?  Other?

Comment: The answers to those questions _may_ prevent the question from being quickly "closed" as too broad / opinion based / etc.

Comment: @RickJames The bottleneck will probably be accessing data from disk if we go beyond our max RAM (Neo4j can keep all the graph in RAM) or with MySQL. Simplicity of coding is important too because we want to avoid that the project takes years if possible... Version management is for the articles that the user write. Whe have to keep previous version and be able to restore the old text. This mean that we have to version some node parameters.

Comment: What will a "peak load" be?

Comment: If I knew what it would be... I lost my crystal ball the day I started programming. Maybe a few thousand of simultaneous users on the same 10 stories.

Comment: Would a 1-second delay be too much during peak loads?

Comment: You probably know that better than me. 1s is acceptable. 3 is probably not.